# Adding new value to creatableselect on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-select

Adding new value to creatableselect on button click.

I am using `CreatableSelect` from `'react-select/creatable'` , and I have to add new value to the select field by clicking on a button,

eg:

[image]

And I don't want to show the `create "text"`.

[image]

here is my code

```
             <>
                <CreatableSelect
                    isMulti 
                    options={ options }
                    isClearable={false}
                    components={{ 
                        DropdownIndicator:() => null, 
                        IndicatorSeparator:() => null
                    }}

                />
                <span className="add-btn" onClick={handleCreateOption}>
                  <i className="bi bi-plus"></i>
                </span>
            </>
```

Answer (score 1):

for the specific scenario i don't think creatable Select is needed you use a simple react select and onClick of the add button add the option. you might need to enable and disable based on if no option is found with specific search.
like

```
      <button
        disabled={
          !!option.filter((option) =>
            option.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          ).length
        }
        onClick={(e) => {
          setOptions([...options, search])
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
```

something like this